# Can't install opencv w/ npm

Tags: node.js, opencv, ubuntu, npm, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to install the [opencv package](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv) for a project I'm working on by running the following:

`npm install opencv --save`

However, every attempt at doing so results in this [long list of errors](http://pastebin.com/Y9uNtLF0)

I've been at a loss with this for a while now, but I'm afraid it may be because I'm not very well versed in working with ubuntu/npm, so the answer may be obvious

**Things to take into consideration:**

- I'm working in a public cloud9 workspace
- Ubuntu 14.04.2
- Node 4.1.1
- npm 2.14.4

Comment: learned that I may need to install opencv by itself first (did so using instructions here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV) but still running into the same error message

Comment: It seems like node is not finding opencv. Make sure you've correctly installed it.

Comment: i'm slowly coming to the conclusion that this may be an issue with ubuntu 14. I didn't notice before but the install for opencv fails, which explains why npm can't find opencv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP here. This ended up being multiple things.

1. the install instructions for OpenCV (help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV) reference outdated packages and therefore do not install properly, and if you're not watching it, you'll miss the fail messages, as the script attempts to continue despite the failed installs.
2. after you get the script to run & install successfully, you'll notice that it installs the latest version of OpenCV, 3.1.0 which is perfectly acceptable.
3. According to the .readme on the node-opencv github, `You'll need OpenCV 2.3.1 or newer installed before installing node-opencv.` you'll end up noticing this statement is partially untrue. In reality, you need any version between 2.3.1 and 2.4.11. Any version after 2.4.11 will result in a failed npm install

Comment: May I ask, so did you end up installing OpenCV 2.4.11 in the end? Do you know if 3.x works with node-opencv meanwhile?

Comment: i ended up going with 2.4.11. i made a [bash](http://pastebin.com/FbdigJ8c) for it too because it was a serious pain to get it running. linked it if you need it

Comment: Thank you so much for the script. No idea why it's still needed in 2021, but it worked great for me.